# How to find the internal energy of a real gas (non ideal)?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature, gas

I have read my thermodynamics book and I'm unable to find where the expression for the internal energy for a real gas comes from: $$dU=C_vdT+(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}dT-P)dV$$ If someone could shine a light on it I'd appreciate it, I have tried to look this online but there is very little result to the internal energy with respect to a real gas, every result is for an ideal gas.

Comment: Please make sure the equation is correctly transcribed; it can’t be correct as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the obvious typo the equation you are asking about is true for any system whose independent variables are $T,V$. Write $S=S(T,V)$, then $dS = \frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}dV$. Apply this expansion for $dS(T,V)$ to the energy conservation law in Gibbs formulation $dU=TdS-pdV$:
$$dU=TdS-pdV = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}dV\right)-pdV\\
=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\left(T\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}-p\right)dV$$
Now according to [Maxwell's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations) integrability relations $\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial T}$ you get:
$$dU=T\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT+\left(T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}-p\right)dV,$$
which is the equation, typo aside, you were asking about.